# Don't find why my function don't change the temperature degree from Celsius to Fahrenheit

Tags: javascript, html

I do a weather app for Free code camp, but i don't know why my button don't change the temperature from celsius to fahrenheit.
I think it's a problem for the recuperation of the variable but i don't know where. 
I try some change in my code but i just go around in circles.

This is my javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function(){


var long;
var lat;
var celsius;
var fahrenheit;


    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){

        long = position.coords.longitude;
        lat = position.coords.latitude;


var url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat='+lat+'&lon='+long+'&lang=fr'+'&units=metric&appid=d475e2ed504ab40f4de6c1b3cba9ebcc';

$.getJSON(url, function(data){
var weatherType = data.weather[0].description;
var windSpeed = data.wind.speed;
var icon = data.weather[0].icon;
var city = data.name;
var country = data.sys.country;
var description = data.weather[0].description;
var celsius = data.main.temp;
var fahrenheit = celsius * 9/5 +32;
var Temp = celsius;

$('.card').html( city + '<br> Temp: '+Temp+' °C'+ '<br> Wind Speed:'+windSpeed+'M/s');
$('.icon').html('<img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/w/' + icon + '.png" /> ' + '<br>'+weatherType);

function change() {
    if (Temp == 'fahrenheit') {
        Temp = 'celsius';
    } else if (Temp == 'celsius') {
        Temp = 'fahrenheit';
    }
$('.btn').on('click', function() { change (); })

console.log(city);
    console.log(weatherType);
    console.log(windSpeed);
    console.log(icon);

        };
      })
    })
  });
```

and the HTML :

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

  <title>Weather App</title>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class='col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 weather' >
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-center card">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-center text-uppercase icon">
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn degree">°C/°F</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center footer">by<a href="http://codepen.io/Th13um/"> Mathieu Dupré-Fontana</a>
  </div>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Can somebody help me please?

Ps: Sorry for my bad English, i'm French .

Comment: `celsius` appears to be a number, not a string

Answer (score 1):

`celsius` appears to be a number, not a string, when `Temp` is set to the value of `celisus`, `Temp` is set to a number, not a string

```
var celsius = data.main.temp;
var fahrenheit = celsius * 9/5 +32;
var Temp = celsius;
```

`Temp` would not be equal to `"fahrenheit"` or `"celcius"` within `change` function

```
function change() {
  if (Temp == 'fahrenheit') {
    Temp = 'celsius';
  } else if (Temp == 'celsius') {
    Temp = 'fahrenheit';
  }
}
```

`.html()` should also be called within `change()` function, if the expected result is to toggle Celcius and Fahrenheit rendering at HTML on `click` at element.